# why isn't my list floated inside my second div?

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

This is my HTML:

```
 <div class="topmenucontainer">
    <div id="topmenu">
    <ul>
    <li style="border-right: 1px solid black;"><a href="">Login</a></li>  
    <li><a href="">Partner Countries</a></li> 
    </ul>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.topmenucontainer {  
    margin:0 auto; 
    border:1px solid red;  
    background-color:#000;
    display:block;
}

#topmenu {  
    margin:0 auto;  
    border:1px solid red;
    /*min-height:25px;*/
    background-color:#fff;
    width:900px;
    display:inline;
}

#topmenu ul {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
    list-style-type: none; 
    float:right;
}

#topmenu ul li {
    float:left;
}
```

And This is how it is displayed

http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/8627/3ktn.jpg

Why the UL isn't displayed where I putted it?I mean why isn't it displayed inside my topmenu div which is white backgrounded and only 900px wide?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a clear:both div to handle the inner floating

```
 <div class="topmenucontainer">
    <div id="topmenu">
      <ul>
        <li style="border-right: 1px solid black;"><a href="">Login</a></li>  
        <li><a href="">Partner Countries</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need any styles on your `.topmenucontainer*`. you can get rid of the `.topmenucontainer` styles

you can try the below styles on `topmenu`. Do you have a final picture of what you are trying to achieve?

```
#topmenu {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 1px solid red;
   background-color: #fff;
   width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/104/b4jk.jpg      this is how in the end should be....see the floating of the 2 menu buttons?:D...Not at the extreme right of the page...but at the right of the 900px div

Comment: I can't get rid of the div topmenucontainer because I need the whole top bar to be black but the 2 buttons to be aligned at right of the 900px div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/73SKM/18/ check this, you can adjust padding based on how much space you need after your links

Comment: the bug in that solution is what if I change resolution?the padding will be the same...

Comment: You can use percentages or ems instead of fixed pixels for padding if you want it to be responsive and scale with resolution.